# Property of function does not exist on type angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Im trying to make a menu image execute a js function to change it's properties by adding the active class to it. I am working with angular on stackblitz and I keep getting the `Property 'openbtn' does not exist on type 'HeaderComponent'` error. I am lost on what to do.

The js file is in angular.json like this: `"scripts": ["src/app/header/assets/js/nav.js"]`

The image which should execute the function:

```
<img
    src="https://myimage.png"
    width="32"
    alt="!"
    class="burger"
    id="burger"
    (click)="openbtn()"
  />
```

The function itself:

```
function openbtn() {
  document.getElementById('burger').onclick = function () {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  };
}
```

header.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare function openbtn(): any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    openbtn();
  }
}
```

Comment: Setting the "onclick" attribute of an element does not do anything; it does not call the function you're assigning.

Comment: Why would you do it that way? The compiler is correct, since it cannot reference the method the way you import it in the ts file. Your logic should be in the typescript (controller) file. The toggle is easy to do once you correct the rest. Please paste a stackblitz link to your issue.